# How to get average of groups of n from filtered table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am writing an exel program where I need to get the average of subgroups with the size n. The data comes from a table which I need to filter sometimes so i cant use the index, because it would in this case use the outfiltered data too. What function can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset (edit your post to include a picture, do not add a link or comment). Then also show what you have tried already. You probably can use INDEX for this, you just need to nest it inside an IF().

Comment: Only two functions in Excel consider using a filter. These are SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE. You should use one of them. But you gave too few details to advise something more specific.

Comment: Are the subgroups disaggregated, a number belongs to one and only one subgroup or do you want something like a moving average (as sometimes used in time based data to smooth out variations)?